# problem with array of std::pair in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, std-pair

I was playing around with some code today, and I came across the idea of putting a bunch of pairs in an array, but I havn't been able to get it to work. Here are the code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
std::pair<double,double> * pairArr;
int main(){
   pairArr = new std::pair<double,double> [3];   //creating the array

   pairArr [0] = make_pair(1.0,1.2);             //Filling arbitrary numbers
   pairArr [1] = make_pair(0.2,1.4);
   pairArr [2] = make_pair(0.8,1.3);

   std::cout<< pair[0].first << pair[1].second << pair[2].first   //Output
   return 0;
}
```

the output of this program is not all what I had input.

Comment: What is the output of the program?

Comment: Stop! Who would cross the Bridge of Death must answer me these questions three, 'ere the other side he see. What is the output of your program? What do you expect the output to have been? What is your question?

Comment: @Robᵩ Why don't I see that more used on SE today ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The program as posted does not compile.

Changing the output to

```
std::cout << pairArr[0].first << pairArr[1].second << pairArr[2].first;
```

produces the expected result, `11.40.8`, that is `1 1.4 0.8` without spaces: https://ideone.com/XAPHX

Comment: +1; My guess is that the "without spaces" is the original problem.